# nServiceBus MSMQ error when subscribing to queue

Tags: nservicebus

This may be something terribly obvious, I am just getting started with nSB.  I will try to be as detailed as I can be.  Lets start with the code:

Here is the endpoint configuration code:
http://www.pastebin.ca/1896246

And the app.config:
http://www.pastebin.ca/1896249

Finally here is the output being logged when I run NServiceBus.Host.exe
http://www.pastebin.ca/1896253

Oddly enough the bus still works and can receive messages and process them, as I see here:
http://www.pastebin.ca/1896257

The last thing that concerns me is that I get repeated `System.Messaging.MessageQueueException` errors while the host process is running:

> Timeout for the requested operation
>   has expired
>
> MessageQueueErrorCode:
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout
>
> StackTrace:    at
>   System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan
>   timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle
>   cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter,
>   MessageQueueTransaction
>   internalTransaction,
>   MessageQueueTransactionType
>   transactionType)

Comment: Ok I realized that in my config I have the same endpoint for the message source and the endpoint which I guess didn't make sense.  When I looked at the Pub/Sub sample I saw that this was not the right way to configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to worry about those MSMQ exceptions as they are internal to NServiceBus and are swallowed by the framework.

Comment: Alright yeah I was thinking that perhaps this was simply the result of opening a request for a message and waiting for a timeout before opening another.  It's just weird to see so many in the debug log.

Answer (score 1):

From the exception it looks like you are performing a receive with a timeout. If there is no message to receive then MSMQ is going to eventually generate an exception when the timeout is reached. You just need to catch the exception and move on if this is an expected scenario (i.e. no message in the queue). If there is ALWAYS a message in the queue then I would be interested in where the cursor is pointing at the time.

Cheers
John Breakwell